# CSS relative container does not scale with margin-child-elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've got the following problem:

I want to have a relative container element that contains some child elements each with margin.

If i dont set the height of the container, it resizes height / width by its containing children.

Problem is that it seems to ignore the margin on them.

here some code:
**css**:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}

.child {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

**html**:

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="child">hello world</div>
    </div>
```

The container should now resize height to 50+20 = 70px,
so if i put another element below it should be ok but it isn't.
Margin seems not to resize containers height, how to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not getting your question quiet well but you are probably missing to clear your `floats`...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjPrK/)

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively you can also use `clear: both;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjPrK/1/)

Comment: ah damn i had inherited the height for my container and set the childrens width + margin independent of this... it actually works well

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the effect you are trying to achieve, either:

1) Add 'overflow:hidden' to the .container div

or

2) Use padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom on the .child div